# Select a tag from different form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms and each form has different `a tag`, but when I use Javascript to use `a tag` different form, I can work on the `a tag` from the `first form`. How can make `Javascript` so that I can work on different `a ta`g from different forms.
My codes are shown below.

```
Form to sell
<body>
<form  class="summarybackground" name="sell"  id="sell" style="height:500px;width:920px;overflow-y:hidden;"  method="post">

<div class="myBox"> 
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Landed</span>
                </a>
            </li>           

        </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="section1">    
        <h1 class="header double">Landed</h1>
      </div> 
</div>
</form>
```

Form to rent

```
<form  class="summarybackground" name="rent"  id="rent" style="height:500px;width:920px;overflow-y:hidden;"  method="post">

<div class="myBox"> 
<nav id="cd-vertical-nav-sec">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
                    <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                    <span class="cd-label">Landed</span>
                </a>
            </li>           

        </ul>
</nav>
<div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="section1">    
        <h1 class="header double">Landed</h1>
      </div> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

This script can work on the first form's a tag only.

```
<script>
$('a').click(function () {
    $('a').removeClass('is-selected');
    $(this).addClass('is-selected');
});
</script>
```

How to make a script so that I can work on both forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your `a` using it's parent

```
<script>
$('#rent a').click(function () {
    $('#rent a').removeClass('is-selected');
    $(this).addClass('is-selected');
});
</script>
```

You can do similar thing for your next form